# How do I get the y axis on a pgfplot to show the values I want, rather than 0 to 1

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I'm trying to draw a pretty simple graph using pgfplot and tikz, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the y axis.

My code is as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {Years},
ylabel = {Current Value},
ymin=0, 
ymax=10000,
ytick={0,2000,4000,6000,8000,10000},
]
\addplot[smooth] file[] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want the y axis to read from 0 to 10000, but currently it shows 0 to 1 on the y axis with a 10^4 floating at the top like so:
[image]

Is there any way I can change this so that it shows 0-10000? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For future reference please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {Years},
ylabel = {Current Value},
ymin=0, 
ymax=10000,
ytick={0,2000,4000,6000,8000,10000},
scaled y ticks = false,
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,10000)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with no y-axis multiplier]

Comment: Thank you that's brilliant

Answer (score 1):

You can change it with `y tick label style`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {Years},
ylabel = {Current Value},
ymin=0, 
ymax=10000,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/precision=0,
    /pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,10000)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]